# Why NSMutableDictionary setValue crashes?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmutabledictionary

`setValue(_:forKey:)` method crashes sometimes. Our `NSMutableDictionary` is written only from main thread, but it is often accessed. Can frequent access of dictionary cause a crash?

I guess with `Core Data` changing data would be more robost, but we decided to use dictionary based persistent storage. Is it any way to make more reliable accessing our `NSMutableDictionary`?

Anyway how could I figure out which `setValue` method crash if they are executed in a loop? If I print `keyPath`, end of loop will be reached before the crash happen, so I can not narrow down which `setValue` call exactly cause the crash.

Comment: You will have to get the crash log and the error message.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, your setup is something like this: writing only on the main thread but reading from another threads. With this setup:

```
let a = NSMutableDictionary()
let time = DispatchTime.now() + 0.01
DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: time) {
    for _ in 0..<10000000000000 {
        let b = self.a["\(self.a.count - 1)"]
        print(b)
    }
}

for index in 0..<1000000000000000 {
    a.setValue(NSNumber(value: index), forKey: "\(index)")
}
```

I was indeed able to reproduce your issue.
Here is the stack trace when the crash is happening:

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x00000001115286f6 in _kernelrpc_mach_vm_deallocate_trap ()
#1  0x0000000111530a43 in mach_vm_deallocate ()
#2  0x00000001112c8477 in mvm_deallocate_pages ()
#3  0x00000001112bfdc4 in free_large ()
#4  0x000000010cc5506b in mdict_rehashd ()
#5  0x000000010cac26c6 in -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] ()
#6  0x000000010b9382f5 in ViewController.viewDidLoad() at 

Thread 5 Queue : com.apple.root.default-qos (concurrent)
#0  0x000000010cafc454 in -[__NSDictionaryM objectForKey:] ()
#1  0x000000010d11567b in NSMutableDictionary.subscript.getter ()
#2  0x000000010d115588 in @objc NSDictionary.subscript.getter ()
#3  0x000000010b93898d in closure #1 in ViewController.viewDidLoad() at
```

From the deallocations on the main thread I guess `setValue` caused some rebucketing on the dictionary, and as a reading happening at the same time, it tries to read deallocated memory -> `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.
Wrapping up: this should be a concurrency issue.

Comment: No no, reading and writing happens on main thread only, but it is quite frequent. No global thread is used.

Comment: I see, then could you post the stacktraces, maybe it can lead closer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely the problem elsewhere. Try setting a breakpoint on exception instead. That way Xcode will stop when it happens.

In the breakpoint navigator choose `Exception breakpoint...`, see picture below.

Note that you might stop at other exceptions too, if they are handled they are not errors. In such case, just continue running.

[image]

Comment: It happens when app is built for distribution. Never on my computer but in testers device downloaded from Test Flight.

Comment: @János Why don't you get the crash log and symbolicate it?

Comment: Xcode delivers crash log, I see in which line it happens, but is it possible to see the value of local variables? I do not think so.